# How to access fetched data through graphql query?

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, gatsby

The code blow fetches an array of data from the server

```
fetch('/api/collections/get/posts?token=xxtokenxx', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        filter: {published:true},
    })
})
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

I need to store this data and grab specific data by using Graphql and I have no idea how to achieve this ( if even it's possible ) through Gatsby js.

Comment: try to add some more screenshots. I don't see that you're using GraphQL endpoint.  What do you have when you're logging a data? show what you have on the server. And basically, I'd suggest you play with GraphQL playground first.

Comment: Do you mean to fetch these data, then import them into gatsby so you can query them with graphql during development?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby distinguishes between the internal GraphQL API, by which you can store and query data internally, and any API it is consuming (such as one provided by a headless CMS), from which you retrieve data by using [source plugins](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-five/).

From the appearance of your URI, it looks like you may be using [Cockpit](https://github.com/agentejo/cockpit) as a CMS, which has a source plugin available for Gatsby: [`gatsby-source-cockpit`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-cockpit/). To install the plugin:

```
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-cockpit
```

To configure the plugin, add the following to `gatsby-config.js`, replacing `http://localhost:8888` with your own Cockpit site:

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-cockpit',
      options: {
        cockpitConfig: {
          baseURL: 'http://localhost:8888',
          folder: '/cockpit',
          accessToken: '4d659efb084077fd24aeb4871d4386',
          collections: ['posts'],
          regions: ['footer'],
          customComponents: [],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```

Now, run:

```
gatsby develop
```

Your local Gatsby site will be available at e.g. `http://localhost:8000/`, after which point you can navigate to `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`, where you can explore your GraphQL schema using GraphiQL.